# Authenticating ldap user with multiple suffix value/domain

Tags: spring, spring-security, active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

I am trying to authenticate and then query AD tree using Spring Ldap Security and Spring Ldap.

Following is my configuration file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-page="/myApp/ldap" default-target-url="/myApp/ldap/config"
            authentication-failure-url="/myApp/ldap?error=true" />
        <logout />
    </http>

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="location">
            <beans:value>classpath:/ldap.properties</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="SystemPropertiesMode">
            <beans:value>2</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="adAuthenticationProvider" scope="prototype"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <!-- the domain name (may be null or empty). If no domain name is configured, it is assumed that the username will always contain the domain name. -->
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="${sample.ldap.domain}" />
        <!-- an LDAP url (or multiple URLs) -->
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="${sample.ldap.url}" />
        <!-- Determines whether the supplied password will be used as the credentials in the successful authentication token. -->
        <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials"
            value="true" />
        <!-- by setting this property to true, when the authentication fails the error codes will also be used to control the exception raised. -->
        <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions"
            value="true" />
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager erase-credentials="false">
        <authentication-provider ref="adAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="location">
            <beans:value>classpath:/ldap.properties</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="SystemPropertiesMode">
            <beans:value>2</beans:value> <!-- OVERRIDE is 2 -->
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <ldap:context-source id="contextSource" 
                         url="${sample.ldap.url}"
                         base="${sample.ldap.base}" 
                         referral="follow"
                         authentication-source-ref="authenticationSource" 
                         base-env-props-ref="baseEnvironmentProperties"/>

    <util:map id="baseEnvironmentProperties">
        <beans:entry key="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout" value="60000" />
        <beans:entry key="java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary" value="objectGUID objectSid"/>
    </util:map>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.SpringSecurityAuthenticationSource" />

    <ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate"
        context-source-ref="contextSource" />

</beans:beans>
```

And property file is -

```
sample.ldap.url=ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3268
sample.ldap.base=dc=example,dc=com
sample.ldap.clean=true
sample.ldap.directory.type=AD
sample.ldap.domain=example.com
```

These setting works fine for following login -

username - example@example.com or example
Password - blah

but fails when i try -
username - example2@example.net or example
Password - blah2

These both are valid logins, and have been validated by login using AD Explorer.

Seems like i need to update my configuration to support UPN suffix/domains as default works fine and other do not.

Is there a way i can append to this config file to support this logic, supporting authenticating/querying multiple domains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason it's not allowing me to login with configured UPN suffix is because `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` seems to be making assumption that UPN suffix is always same as Domain Name.

Please refer this post - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3204

I think there should be a better way to handle this though, or maybe better library for authentication.

Answer (score 4):

To explain @NewBee's solution:

1 `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`:

- Specialized `LDAP authentication provider` which uses Active Directory configuration conventions.
- It will authenticate using the Active Directory [userPrincipalName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680857%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [sAMAccountName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679635%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or a custom `searchFilter`) in the form `username@domain`. If the `username` does not already end with the `domain` name, the `userPrincipalName` will be built by appending the configured domain name to the username supplied in the `authentication request`. If no domain name is configured, it is assumed that the username will always contain the domain name.
- The user authorities are obtained from the data contained in the `memberOf` attribute.

2 `LDAP authentication in Spring Security`:

- Obtaining the unique LDAP `Distinguished Name`, or DN, from the login name.

  - This will often mean performing a `search` in the directory, unless the exact mapping of usernames to DNs is known in advance. So a user might enter his/her name when logging in, but the actual name used to `authenticate` to LDAP will be the full DN, such as `uid=(username),ou=users,dc=springsource,dc=com`.
- `Authenticating the user`, either by `binding` as that user or by performing a remote `compare` operation of the user's password against the password attribute in the directory entry for the DN.
- Loading the list of authorities for the user.

For a reference to [How to configure multiple UPN Suffixes](http://www.rebeladmin.com/2015/01/how-to-configure-multiple-user-principal-name-upn-suffixes/). Plus in `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` you could write a function for reading multiple suffixes, as the library is [adaptable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30879635/7707749).